# Alamofire Response Serialization Error

Tags: swift, alamofire

I see this kind of error in the services which I use very often. I'm showing the errors from the fabric

[image]

Example alamofire call in application.

[image]

I tried a few solutions but I could not get it. I changed optimization level but I still keep getting the error.

[image]

Who is responsible for this error? Client, Server, Alamofire?

Comment: are you sure the response is in JSON format?

Comment: yes, I get the error occasionally.